# How to test for mediation with a continuous mediator and DV, but a categorical predictor?

Tags: regression, spss, categorical-data, mediation

I want to explore whether attitudes mediate the relationship between employment status and intention to apply to graduate school.  (See image below).

I planned to use the Sobel Test to explore the mediation, but I'm not sure I can. How does one/how can one test for mediation with a categorical predictor and both a continuous mediator variable and dependent variable? Prefer answers oriented to SPSS.

[image]

Comment: Your diagram is helpful, although I'd like to know for sure what "aggregated 5 item scale" means.

Comment: The fact that the predictor is categorical is irrelevant. All the standard methods apply.

Answer (score 1):

To test mediation effect (full or partial), you can you **Sobel's test** [As it suffers from normality issues for small samples, **Bootstrapping** is more preferred approach.]

Both can be done in SPSS by using **process macro by Andrew F. Hayes**.
See [for more details](http://afhayes.com/index.html)

After installing process macro in SPSS; follow these steps:

- Analyze > Regression > Process by Andrew F. Hayes
- Select DV, IDV and mediating variable; select **model number 4**; select number of bootstrap samples; and in Options, click on Sobel's test and other required statistics; click

Screenshots of steps:
 [Analyze > Regression > Process by Andrew F. Hayes](http://afhayes.com/index.html)
[image: Select DV, IDV and mediating variable; select **model number 4**; select number of bootstrap samples; and in Options, click on Sobel's test and other required statistics; click]

[[image: Select DV, IDV and mediating variable; select **model number 4**; select number of bootstrap samples; and in Options, click on Sobel's test and other required statistics; click]